# Convert amount to word in Python

Tags: python

Would you help me to convert amount to word in Spanish?
I am using num2word library but you can see some decimal points not converted properly.

```
>>> from num2words import num2words
>>> num2words(9036.20)
u'nine thousand and thirty-six point two zero'
>>> num2words(9036.21)
u'nine thousand and thirty-six point two zero'
>>> num2words(9036.55)
u'nine thousand and thirty-six point five four'
>>> num2words(9036.55, lang='es')
u'nueve mil treinta y seis punto cinco cuatro'
```

Kindly share your valuable experience.

Comment: Can't you post text instead of an image? Secondly this is an English site. Most of us won't know Spanish here to help you :/

Comment: @Bhargav, "its in english" and you can't see screenshot ?

Comment: Ahem *Would you help me to convert amount to word in* ***Spanish language***

Comment: Its clearly an issue with the number parsing and not the language, as both languages say the same thing (with my limited spanish knowledge). Did you consider raising a bug against `num2word`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As an aside: a Spanish language of Stack Overflow [is now in the public beta stage](https://es.stackoverflow.com/).

[This is a known issue with num2word](https://github.com/savoirfairelinux/num2words/issues/1) and the solution is to use `Decimal` and convert the float value as a string

```
>>> from num2words import num2words
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> num2words(Decimal(str(9036.55)), lang='es')
>>> u'nueve mil treinta y seis punto cinco cinco'
```